# Easljs Applying filters to bitmap

Tags: javascript, html, createjs

I'm trying to figure out how to add filters ti a video source with easljs. According to the documentation, I can just set filters to the `bitmap.filtes` property. This doesn't seem to work though. There is no error or anything, the filters are just not applied at all.

One confusion about the documentation, is that it mentions that `cache()` must be called on the display object in order for filters to be applied but for the `bitmap` class, it says that `cache()` should not be called.

Below is the code that I'm using as a test:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage('screen');

var video =  document.getElementById('source');
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(video);

bitmap.scaleX = 0.44;
bitmap.scaleY = 0.44;
bitmap.y = 30;

bitmap.filters = [
    new createjs.ColorFilter(0,0,0,1,255,0,0),
    new createjs.BoxBlurFilter(5, 5, 10)
];

stage.addChild(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation regarding Bitmap and Filters is misleading - and I will make sure it is updated for the next release.

Caching of a bitmap should be avoided because it will NOT provide any performance benefit, which you will get from caching containers, shapes, and Text. In fact, it can even degrade performance instead because it will use additional memory to store the cached version

But you MUST cache a bitmap to apply filters to it. Add a cache call to your sample, and it should work.

Sorry for any confusion that is caused by the documentation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. When I add `bitmap.cache()` to the above code, however, it seems to throw an exception: `Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11`

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by the cache? DOM Exception 11 is usually related to ajax requests. Can you isolate the cache code and test it? Are you perhaps loading content cross-domain?